# How to have two sort options in PostgreSQL RECURSIVE

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have the following query that recursively organises comments and their replies.

```
WITH RECURSIVE comment_tree AS (
    SELECT 
        id                AS comment_id, 
        body              AS comment_body, 
        reply_to          AS comment_reply_to, 
        1                 AS level, 
        "createdAt"       AS comment_date, 
        commenter_id, 
        article_id, 
        array["createdAt"] AS path_info
   FROM "Comments" 
   WHERE "reply_to" IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 
        c.id, 
        c.body, 
        c.reply_to, 
        p.level + 1, 
        "createdAt", 
        c.commenter_id, 
        c.article_id,
        p.path_info || c."createdAt"
   FROM "Comments" c
   JOIN comment_tree p ON c.reply_to = comment_id
)
SELECT 
    comment_id, 
    path_info,
    comment_body, 
    comment_reply_to, 
    comment_date, 
    level, 
    U.first_name, 
    U.last_name, 
    coalesce(U.username, CAST(U.id AS VARCHAR)) AS username
FROM comment_tree
LEFT JOIN 
    "Users" U ON commenter_id = U.id 
        WHERE article_id = '62834723-B804-4CA1-B984-D949B1A7E1E2'
ORDER BY path_info DESC;
```

From what I can see... this is working well so far except for the sorting.

Currently the comments are sorted oldest to newest. which then nests the replies underneath correctly but I want the parent list to be newest to oldest.

Is there a way I can sort the child values DESC and the Parents ASC?

eg.

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | reply_to |   date   |
+----+----------+----------+
| C1 | null     | 01052016 | < - Oldest
| C2 | null     | 02052016 |
| C3 | C1       | 03052016 |
| C4 | C1       | 04052016 |
| C5 | null     | 05052016 |
| C6 | C4       | 06052016 |
| C7 | C2       | 07052016 |
| C8 | C6       | 08052016 | < - Newest 
|    |          |          |
+----+----------+----------+
```

desired result

```
| C5 (Newest Parent first)
| C2
  | C7
| C1
  | C3 (Oldest Child first for all tiers below parent)
  | C4
    | C6
      | C8
```

Comment: Just a hint: `... order by case when reply_to is null then id end desc, id asc;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd introduce an artificial column `sort` in the *Common Table Expression*.

With `Comments`defined like this:

```
            Table "laurenz.Comments"
┌───────────┬───────────────────────┬───────────┐
│  Column   │         Type          │ Modifiers │
├───────────┼───────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ id        │ character varying(10) │ not null  │
│ reply_to  │ character varying(10) │           │
│ createdAt │ date                  │ not null  │
└───────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────┘
Indexes:
    "comment_tree_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "comment_tree_reply_to_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (reply_to) REFERENCES "Comments"(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE ""Comments"" CONSTRAINT "comment_tree_reply_to_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (reply_to) REFERENCES "Comments"(id)
```

I'd write something like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE comment_tree AS (
   SELECT id, reply_to, "createdAt",
          CAST(current_date - "createdAt" AS text) AS sort
      FROM "Comments"
      WHERE reply_to IS NULL
   UNION ALL SELECT c.id, c.reply_to, c."createdAt",
                    substring(p.sort FROM '^[^-]*') || '-' || c."createdAt"
      FROM "Comments" c
           JOIN comment_tree p ON c.reply_to = p.id
)
SELECT id, reply_to, "createdAt"
FROM comment_tree
ORDER BY sort;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I switched CURRENT_DATE to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP because I am using timestamp. Thank you so much!

Comment: On further inspection this doesn't work as expected, it works for the top level and first reply but subsequent reply levels are just a list ordered by date ignoring parent ordering.

Comment: Right, that's what I understood you wanted. The idea is probably the same, if more complicated - tag the rows in a way that corresponds to your desired ordering.

Comment: It helped me understand CTE a huge amount so I am still entirely grateful, thanks again.